# Registration page for Web Site

Tags: manual-testing

How will you write the test case for registration page? The page contain following information....First Name, Last Name, Mobile NO, Country, Address, Postal code, Username, password, email address, then submit....

Comment: We aren't here to design your test cases for you. You have to do some work, show your research, describe your test environment and so on.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: I knew the test cases for my question. I want to know the comments given here are comes under validation test or functional test cases?

Answer (score 1):

I will open Xmind and prepare a mind map of the test ideas which i will decide depending on the priorities, risks, time availability and cost. Then I will get feedback by someone and see if I have missed out anything...

Answer (score 0):

Roughly I will check following things:
1. Verify each and every field for number of characters, is mandatory, any restrictions (like only numbers allowed, only chars allowed etc), validations for email address
2. Is it possible to submit without entering mandatory fields?
3. Is it possible to use same email ID twice?
4. What happens on cancel button?
5. Possible to login with the registered details?
6. Are registered details saved correctly in database?

and so on...

Comment: all above are functional test case or it comes under validation

Answer (score 0):

- Mandatory fields marked with asterisks
- Proper validation testing (client side and server side validations)
- Mandatory fields must not be entered empty
- Maximum and minimum character limit for each field
- Email address field must properly validated (with regex)
- Mobile number format must be proper
- Postal code validation
- Proper database testing all fields must be inserted in DB
- Proper redirection to thank you page
- Email must be sent after registration process

More test cases can be generated depending on the requirements

Comment: While these are all useful suggestions, they aren't necessarily going to be viable test cases. Required fields aren't always marked with asterisks, not all registrations send emails, there are multiple different phone number and postal code formats in use, and so forth. It all depends on the requirements of the application.

Comment: I understand, what you wrote above is all validation testing or is it functional test case?